# Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is connected, has a compact closure, but is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology

> Describe a subspace $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which is connected, whose closure (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) is compact, but with the property that $X$ is not locally compact.

I'm thinking the following space satisfies these properties:

$$X = \{ (0,0) \} \cup \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -1 \leq y \leq 1, x > 0\}$$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  Your subspace is connected and not locally compact.  However its closure $$\overline{X} = [ 0 , + \infty ] \times [ -1 , 1 ]$$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (recall the Heine-Borel Theorem).  The simple fix would be to just ensure that the projection onto the $x$-axis is not unbounded:
$$
X = \{ (0,0) \} \cup \{ (x,y) : -1 \leq y \leq 1, 0 < x \leq 1 \}.
$$